# In an Ember route how can I check if an action exists?

Tags: ember.js

In a component it is really easy to have an optional action provided to the component. In the JS of the component I can write:

```
if (this.get('someAction')) {
  this.sendAction('someAction');
}
```

In my application route I have a 'generic action' that saves me providing widget components with long lists of actions, it looks like this:

```
genericAction: function(customActionName, customActionParams) {
  this.send(customActionName, customActionParams);
}
```

For various reasons (including using genericAction in some components to fire an action a test could subscribe to, but the app not necessarily use in some hard to test async/pretender workflows) I would prefer to check the action exists, i.e:

```
genericAction: function(customActionName, customActionParams) {
  if (this.get(customActionName)) {
    this.send(customActionName, customActionParams);
  }
}
```

Similar to how you can in a component, however this does not work, nor does `this.controller.get(customActionName)`.

Other than keeping a hard coded list of actions, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you keep your actions in the routes/application.js file itself then the code would be

**In Ember 2.0 or later:**

```
   if(Em.get(this.actions, actionName)) {
         this.send(actionName);
   }
```

**In Ember 1.13**

this.actions is undefined in Ember 1.13, you have to use this._actions

```
   if(Em.get(this._actions, actionName)) {
         this.send(actionName);
   }
```

If you need to support both Ember 1.x and 2.x then use something like:

```
   let actions = this.actions || this._actions;
   if(Em.get(actions, actionName)) {
         this.send(actionName);
   }
```

If you keep your actions in the application controller (controllers/application.js) then siva - abc's answer works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the actions in `controller.actions`. In your case, you have to check as

```
   if(Em.get(this.controller.actions, actionName)) {
         this.get('controller').send(actionName);
   }
```

Here is a [demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/18f1e3d2a2aae62e95d5)

Comment: There is a missing enclosing bracket I guess:

     `if(Em.get(this.controller.actions, actionName)) {
         this.get('controller').send(actionName);
       }`

Answer (score 0):

if you are in a component you can use

```
   if (this.get('yourActionName')) { }
```